# Direct access to a single pixel using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel, imaging

Is there any way with Python to directly get (only get, no modify) a single pixel (to get its RGB color) from an image (compressed format if possible) without having to load it in RAM nor processing it (to spare the CPU)?

---

More details:

My application is meant to have a huge database of images, and only of images.

So what I chose is to directly store images on harddrive, this will avoid the additional workload of a DBMS.

However I would like to optimize some more, and I'm wondering if there's a way to directly access a single pixel from an image (the only action on images that my application does), without having to load it in memory.

Does PIL pixel access allow that? Or is there another way?

The encoding of images is my own choice, so I can change whenever I want. Currently I'm using PNG or JPG. I can also store in raw, but I would prefer to keep images a bit compressed if possible. But I think harddrives are cheaper than CPU and RAM, so even if images must stay RAW in order to do that, I think it's still a better bet.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

So, as I feared, it seems that it's impossible to do with variable compression formats such as PNG.

I'd like to refine my question:

- Is there a constant compression format (not necessarily specific to an image format, I'll access it programmatically), which would allow to access any part by just reading the headers?
- Technically, how to efficiently (read: fast and non blocking) access a byte from a file with Python?

**SOLUTION**

Thank's to all, I have successfully implemented the functionality I described by using run-length encoding on every row, and padding every row to the same length of the maximum row.

This way, by prepeding a header that describes the fixed number of columns for each row, I could easily access the row using first a file.readline() to get the headers data, then file.seek(headersize + fixedsize*y, 0) where y is the row currently selected.

Files are compressed, and in memory I only fetch a single row, and my application doesn't even need to uncompress it because I can compute where the pixel is exactly by just iterating over every RLE values. So it is also very easy on CPU cycles.

Comment: PIL has pixel methods, but does require you to load the entire image. You might be able to do what you want if you have bitmaps though. "Raw" doesn't really  correspond to any particular file format.

Comment: In order to access a single pixel from an image PIL needs to first read the whole image.  Could you tell us more why you need this?  There may be a better approach.

Comment: I added a bit more description on the question.

To further detail my intent, I just need to get a single pixel from an image for any call to my script. That's why I think it's a waste of resources to load an entire image to RAM (RAM and CPU waste).

So that's why I would like to directly access a pixel from an image, directly by reading the byte from the harddrive.

I would prefer a library that would support compressed formats (by doing some ingenious computations), but my alternative right now is to just store images as RAW and then I think it would be quite easy to access a single byte.

Comment: Also, when I say that I just need to access a pixel from an image, I mean that I just need to get the RGB value for that pixel, then my application does some stuff depending on the value found.

Comment: If you want random access, you'll need to go raw. You will have to read the whole thing in memory to deal with compressed formats like JPG and PNG. Also, be careful with lossy compression formats like JPG, where a specific pixel might have a color completely different from the perceived color in its vicinity.

Comment: @NullUserException: yes indeed, I use JPG for other images that I do not want to access programmatically. Could you please point me to a function or a way to efficiently do a random access using Python?

Comment: "Constant compression" is almost a contradiction in terms.

Comment: To read an arbitrary portion of a file in Python, use [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to move the file pointer. For you other question, I suppose it would be possible create an optimized function that can give you an arbitrary part of a compressed file without uncompressing the whole thing, but this isn't typically how archives are used so you'd have to do it yourself.

Comment: @ MarkRansom: I know but a constant compression would still be better than no compression...
@NullUserException: yes that would be great, but I have no idea which compression algorithm would allow (at least theoretically) to do that.

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html For fast pixel manipulation ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a compressed file format, you can break each image up into smaller rectangles and store them separately. Using a fixed size for the rectangles will make it easier to calculate which one you need. When you need the pixel value, calculate which rectangle it's in, open that image file, and offset the coordinates to get the proper pixel.

This doesn't completely optimize access to a single pixel, but it can be much more efficient than opening an entire large image.

Comment: In fact I was just thinking about a similar idea and was going to update my question when I saw your answer. I think I'll do just that, but with a twist. My images are just 2 colors: black and white, and I have BIG contiguous zones, so I can easily compress all columns of each row like this: 10B12W8B etc.. This way I can easily access a row just like in a RAW file, but then I can access the columns by just a simple computation of ranges with my column coordinate (check if it's in the 10 first black pixels, if not then in the 12 next white, etc...). I keep your idea in store, nice one too!

Comment: @user1121352, a 1-high rectangle is still a rectangle.

Comment: Indeed :D But I can store it in a single file, which will preserve the exact position of my pixels more easily.

Answer (score 1):

In order to evalutate a file you have to load into memory. However, you might be able to figure out how to read only parts of a file, depending on the file format. For example the PNG file specifies a header of size of 8 bytes. However, because of compression the chunks are variable. But if you would store all the pixels in a raw format, you can directly access each pixel, because you can calculate the adress of the file and the appropriate offset. What PNG, JPEG is going to do with the raw data is impossible to predict.

Depending on the structure of the files you might be able to compute efficient hashes. I suppose there is loads of research, if you want to really get into this, for example: [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/899541)

"This paper introduces a novel image indexing technique that may be called an image hash function. The algorithm uses randomized signal processing strategies for a non-reversible compression of images into random binary strings, and is shown to be robust against image changes due to compression, geometric distortions, and other attacks"

Comment: Thank's for the paper, interesting, I'll read it.

That's what I thought about variable compression... Then is there a constant compression format that would allow to directly access a byte? This surely seems possible...

Comment: There are several purposes, so I don't know what you use case looks like. You basically try to create a function, such that each image has unique short identifier. A trivial example: if the first 10 pixels are unique to each picture, you can ignore the rest, because in terms of search, it doesn't add any value. That is sort of what a hash is. You reduce search immensely, if you use the structure of your data. This is not always impossible, which is why search is not a trivial problem.

Comment: No then this is a different application: my images are very random, but they are only black and white, and there are big contiguous zones (eg: there's no 1px of a color with all neighbours of the other color). Anyway thank's that's a good read with a lot of other interesting applications.